# IBM Worklight 6.0 - .war file deployment fails

Tags: deployment, ibm-mobilefirst, war, worklight-server

I've installed IBM Worklight v6.0 Consumer Edition with WAS Liberty Profile 8.5.5 on a linux server and an oracle database.

I've built a .war with IBM Worklight Studio v6.0 and deployed it in my Liberty apps' directory /worklightServer/apps.
Then I changed server.xml with the following:

```
<!-- Configuration for Test app -->
<application id="TestApp" name="TestApp" location="TestProjectWL6.war" type="war">
  <classloader delegation="parentLast">
    <commonLibrary>
        <fileset dir="${shared.resource.dir}/lib" includes="worklight-jee-library.jar"/>
    </commonLibrary>
  </classloader>
</application>
```

The .war file does not get deployed because of following errors in messages.log:

> [7/5/13 14:42:47:289 CEST] 00000012
>   m.ibm.ws.app.manager.internal.statemachine.ResolveFileAction E
>   CWWKZ0021E: Application TestApp at location TestProjectWL6.war is
>   invalid.

How to make the .war valid? I followed the IBM Worklight and WebSphere Information Centers on how to deploy, but it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've cleaned all my environment: remove all applications config in server.xml (including application center console installed with worklight server installation), remove every war from apps & dropins directory.

then i built with ant task, and now it's ok.

Comment: Good to hear you got it working; please mark your answer as Answered you are able to. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The error identifier [CWWKZ0021E](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.messages.doc/com.ibm.ws.app.manager.internal.resources.AppManagerMessages.html) suggests a problem with the "archive or directory at the specified location". I would make sure that

- The file usr/servers/worklightServer/apps/TestProjectWL6.war exists (file name case being significant),
- It is really a file, not a directory.
- Its access rights don't prevent the Liberty server process from reading it. Use `ls -l .../usr/servers/worklightServer/apps/TestProjectWL6.war` to check it.
- It is not truncated (i.e. `unzip -l .../usr/servers/worklightServer/apps/TestProjectWL6.war` gives a reasonable listing of its contents).
- The server.xml you modified is really the one in usr/servers/worklightServer/ and not the one belonging to a different server.

This all sounds stupid, but these kinds of things occasionally are wrong when manual application server configuration is performed. Configuration through the Ant task `<configureApplicationServer>` is more reliable.

Comment: the file exists with correct case, it's really a file, the chmod is 777, it's not truncated (correct zip file) and the server.xml is the one...

Answer (score 0):

How did you install IBM Worklight v6.0?
How did you deploy your project's .war file?

Did you use the supplied Ant scripts that are copied to disk when using the IBM Worklight Installation Manager?

The process of installing Worklight Server as well as deploying a .war file in IBM Worklight  v6.0 is much different than it was in v5.

Make sure you follow the updated documentation:

- [Installing Worklight Server](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/admin/c_installation.html)
- [Deploying an IBM Worklight project](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/deploy/c_deploy_wl_project.html)

I am willing to bet you did not use the Ant scripts to deploy the .war file; Most likely you are pointing to the wrong location of the Worklight JEE .jar file. You will need to correct the path.

I suggest using the supplied Ant scripts.

Comment: i've installed IBM Worklight v6.0 with imcl command with a response file, and use of the ant scripts was automatic (post-install process). i've followed the documentation of the InfoCenter, but the war is not deployed...

Comment: You mention you manually deployed the .war file. That's not the way to do it, rather you should use the supplied Ant scripts. Did you follow the same Information Center pages I have linked you to?

Comment: i've followed the pages you've linked, and my choice was to do a manual deployment as described in the section "Deploying a project WAR file and configuring the application server manually".